Vertically Center div Using Bootstrap
I'm currently working with a template, and I'm trying to position the elements with the following requirements:

The header must stick to the top, be horizontally centered, with spacing between the H3 and the set of <nav> links.
The <main> must be horizontally and vertically centered, with text-alignment being to the right.

I've been at this for 3 hours and I still haven't managed to get it to work. Here is the template:
  <div>
    <header className='fixed-top d-flex justify-content-around'>
      <div className="">
        <h3 className="float-md-start mb-0">Ethan Leyden</h3>
        <nav className="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
          <a className="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a className="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Features</a>
          <a className="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div className="mx-auto my-auto">
      <main className="">
        <h1>Welcome to the site</h1>
        <p className="lead">It's definitely still under construction. Do you know how to vertically center content with Bootstrap? I sure don't</p>
        <p className="lead">
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-lg btn-light fw-bold border-white bg-white">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>

I've tried various combinations of mx-auto, my-auto, align-items-center, d-flex but to no avail. I'm sure this is a trivial question but I can't find the answer anywhere to my specific question (or find one that works, at least).

"The  must be horizontally and vertically centered, with text-alignment being to the right.". How this is possible you want text align to right and center both ?

Your first requirement is getting fulfill by using flexbox or using d-flex. Lean about flex here and to playaround use this



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex flex-column vh-100">
    <header class='fixed-top d-flex justify-content-around'>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-5 justify-content-center">
            <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0">Ethan Leyden</h3>
            <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
<div class="mx-auto flex-grow-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100 mt-5">
    <main class="">
        <h1>Welcome to the site</h1>
        <p class="lead">It's definitely still under construction. Do you know how to vertically center
            content with Bootstrap? I sure don't</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light fw-bold border-white bg-white">Learn more</a>
        </p>
    </main>
</div>
    <div class="mx-auto my-auto">
     
    </div></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>




What’s the difference between this and the answer given eight hours prior to yours?

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
